# Laplacian of minimal distance of a point to a curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, plane-curves

Take a parametrized curve $(x, f(x))$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Assume that at $0$ the map $x \mapsto f(x)$ assumes a local maximum and that $f(x)$ is symmetric about $0$ (I add this just for the sake of simplicity) and $f(0)>0$.

Now, let $d(x)$ be minimal distance of the point $(x,0)$ from our curve. In an article I am reading the authors claim the formula $$\partial_x^2 d(x) = \frac{\kappa(p(x))}{1-\kappa(p(x))d(x)},$$
where $p(x)$ is the point in which the distance is obtained, i.e.: $d(x)=\| (x-p(x),-f(p(x)))\|$.

The formula should not hold for all $x$, but only in a neighborhood of $0$, assuming that $d(0) \leq \delta,$ for some small $\delta$.

The formula makes perfect sense to me, since by approximation through osculating circles one can imagine that some singularity occurs when $d(x)\geq\frac{1}{\kappa}.$ Still, I do not know how to show it, and I wonder whether there is a nice differential-geometric argument to see this.

---

My attempt so far, which leads to a wrong formula, is to simply differentiate the distance:

\begin{align*}
\partial_x d(x) & = \frac{1}{2 d(x)} \partial_x [(x-p(x))^2 +f(p(x))^2 ] \\
& = \frac{(x-p(x))(1-p'(x))+ f(p(x))f'(p(x))p'(x)}{d(x)}\\
& = 0,
\end{align*}
the latter if evaluated in $x=0$, since we have $p(0)= f'(0)=0$. For the second derivative:
\begin{align*}
\partial_x^2 d(0) & = \frac{1}{2 d(0)} \partial_x^2 [(x-p(x))^2 +f(p(x))^2 ] \vert_{x=0} \\
& = \frac{(1-p'(0))^2+ f(0)f''(0)(p'(0))^2}{d(x)} \\
& =  \kappa (0),
\end{align*}
since by symmetry (but it might be true in general) $p'(0)=1$. Of course, I don't see my error. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there some geometric intuition to this?

Comment: Maybe a more intuitive way to phrase the problem is to ask, what is the curvature of the level sets associated to the distance? Locally, the distance determines sort of a foliation (I guess, my diffgeo is what it is).

Comment: We expect the curvature of these level sets to blow up as we come closer to the center of the osculating circle, which is what the correct formula is telling us.